# How to add network printer remotely without knowing the IP?

Tags: drivers, printer, network-printer

Assume your friend from over 100km away asked you to add a network printer to his computer since you're so tech savvy.
How would you add network printer remotely in this case?

You would need:
0. Remote connection to your friend's computer
1. Printer IP and brand/model names
2. Respective drivers downloaded either from manufacturer's website or Windows Update driver

Question is, how would you find out the IP address of the printer without bothering your friend too much with technical steps? Since your friend isn't as tech savvy as you - they wouldn't know which buttons to press to get IP address.

Comment: Ignore the unhelpful comment @Steve. Welcome to SuperUser

Comment: its not in the least bit unhelpful.  it will most likely contain the answer.

Comment: Usually, auto-discovery takes care of this. I don’t see the need to know the address at all. All modern printers use NetBIOS, Bonjour and the like to advertise their presence and services.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even try to do what you've intimated. I would instead get the friend to install (if only temporarily) TeamViewer or something similar.

I would then remotely connect to his PC and either talk him through adding the printer or do it for him.

Indeed, this is exactly what I do with family members who need support when hundreds of miles away.

TeamViewer (and other similar tools) allow you to connect through complex networks very easily and make the whole process very simple.

An alternative is to use a web conference type facility such as Lync or WebEx. This is what I'd use in a professional capacity (when I am not an admin of the system but need to remotely help or demonstrate something).

Answer (score 0):

You need to download some IP scanner on his computer, scan and hopefully find the printer.

I'd first suggest you to try this utility:
http://www.technibble.com/page-countster-repair-tool-of-the-week/
It scans your network pretty fast, and returns (usually) only printers.

If that doesn't work, try a regular IP scanner (I like [Angry IP scanner](http://angryip.org/download/))

Another idea, if for some reason you'll need it, is to look in the router.
You can see what's the DHCP scope is, and maybe what addresses are allocated.